# There is no way to transfer an UIImage from iPhone to WKInterfaceImage in the WatchKit app, correct?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, watchkit, wkinterfaceimage

There is no way to transfer an UIImage from iPhone to WKInterfaceImage in the WatchKit app, correct?

There are limitations that will not allow that, correct?

Then I tried saving it in the documents folder on the device. But those are 2 seperate folders on each device, correct? The iPhone has a documents folder. And the one on the Watch device is a separate one. So when I query the file path, it gives me something like Device/pluginKit/filename.png on the Watch.

In short there is no way to achieve the above title, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share disk space/files between your host iOS app and your WatchKit extension, you'll need to use App Groups. Check out the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html ("Sharing Data with Your Containing iOS App")

WKInterfaceImage, however, has a couple methods for using an image from the phone. I've put together a quick explanation here: http://www.fiveminutewatchkit.com/blog/2015/3/10/how-to-display-an-image-using-wkinterfaceimage

Comment: Hosting provider was having issues. Fixed now.